# order MATCH AGAINST by relevance or search the exact phrase

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I want to search multiple value in one column and i want my query to return the exact searched phrase ( in this case tag)

here is my query

```
SELECT *
FROM `image_tags`
WHERE
MATCH (
tag
)
AGAINST (
'"yy yy"' '"xxxx"' IN BOOLEAN MODE
)
LIMIT 40
```

but i get lots of unwanted results which only have part of searched tags in them

```
xxxx
aaxaa
bbxb
yy yy
```

that's fine by me but at least  i want the result to be ordered by relevance to the searched tags , i have this but it doesn't work

```
SELECT * , MATCH (
tag
)
AGAINST (
'"yy yy"' '"xxxx"' IN BOOLEAN MODE
) as rel
FROM `image_tags`
WHERE
MATCH (
tag
)
AGAINST (
'"yy yy"' '"xxxx"' IN BOOLEAN MODE
)
order by rel desc 
LIMIT 30
```

**btw my searched tags are in persian not english **

here is my actuall query

```
SELECT *
FROM `image_tags`
WHERE
MATCH (
tag
)
AGAINST (
'"مردم تبریز" "ماسوله"'
)
LIMIT 40
```

here is the result (i've added stars to unwanted results in the list )

```
    id      image_id tag
    342145  123566  مردم تبریز
    342413  123564  مردم تبریز
    342143  123567  مردم تبریز
    342142  123569  مردم تبریز
    342137  123572  مردم تبریز
    342414  123561  مردم تبریز
    294921  106946  ترس از مردم = سلطه مردم بر من   ******   
    80529   29913   ماسوله
    452056  160815  ماسوله
    449178  159809  ماسوله
    75373   28164   ماسوله
    75402   28164   ماسوله
    13928   10031   ماسوله 2      ***********
    13927   10030   ماسوله
    358365  129393  کوه های ماسوله   ***************
```

Comment: @eggyal i've added the exact query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As documented under [String Literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-literals.html):

> Quoted strings placed next to each other are concatenated to a single string. The following lines are equivalent:
>
> ```
> 'a string'
> 'a' ' ' 'string'
> ```

Therefore, `"مردم تبریز" "ماسوله"` is equivalent to `"مردم تبریزماسوله"`.  You should instead *quote the entire string literal*, which itself contains quoted elements e.g. `'"مردم تبریز" "ماسوله"'`.  That is, change:

```
MATCH (tag) AGAINST ("مردم تبریز" "ماسوله" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

To this:

```
MATCH (tag) AGAINST ('"مردم تبریز" "ماسوله"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Comment: thanx  , much better specially when i remove `IN BOOLEAN MODE` but still  i get couple of  unwanted result  .... i've updated example query in my question

Comment: @max: Of the three 'unwanted' results shown in your latest edit, the first one contains `"مردم"` whilst the final two both contain  `"ماسوله"`.  If you used `IN BOOLEAN MODE`, the first would be omitted (because it matches neither of the searched phrases - it only contains a single word from `"مردم تبریز"`) whereas the latter two would still be included because they still match one of the searched phrases, `"مردم"`.  It isn't clear why these results are unwanted.

Comment: @max: If you want exact matches only, why are you using fulltext search?  Why not instead use `WHERE tag IN ("مردم تبریز" ,"ماسوله")`?

Comment: BECUZ IT'S MUCH FASTER TO USE FULL-TEXT OR AT LEAST I THINK !? SHOULD I JUST AD NORMAL INDEX TO TAG COLUMN AND USE `TAG IN (` ?

Comment: @max: Did someone just whack you over the head with your keyboard or something?  No, fulltext indexes are efficient for scanning the full text for your desired match; they are of *no use whatsoever* for finding exact matches.  A B-Tree index together with equality comparisons, such as `IN()`, is exactly what you want.